# Rotate image using asp.net c# through textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, gdi+, gdi

how to rotate image through put in angle value in textbox using graphics in asp.net c#?
I take a textbox and image and button.I want to give value in angle in textbox and image will be rotate according to given value.so,i can only doing a simple button_click event ,but it is not proper for textbox.so,give simple code ...

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = Server.MapPath(Image1.ImageUrl);

        ////create an image object from the image in that path
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path);

        ////rotate the image
       img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipXY);

        ////save the image out to the file
        img.Save(path);

        ////release image file
        img.Dispose();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code save the rotated image into newfile.png in current project folder path

Try This:

```
 protected void Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         string path = Server.MapPath(Image1.ImageUrl);
         string newpath =Server.MapPath(@"~/filename.png");

        ////create an image object from the image in that path
        System.Drawing.Bitmap img =new  System.Drawing.Bitmap(path);      

        Bitmap map = RotateBitmap(COnvert.ToSingle(textBox1.Text), img);
        map.Save(newpath);




        ////release image file
        img.Dispose();
    }
     public Bitmap RotateBitmap(float Angle, Bitmap bm_in)
    {
        try
        {
            float wid = bm_in.Width;
            float hgt = bm_in.Height;
            Point[] corners = { new Point(0, 0), new Point(int.Parse(wid.ToString()), 0), new Point(0, int.Parse(hgt.ToString())), new Point(int.Parse(wid.ToString()), int.Parse(hgt.ToString())) };
            int cx = int.Parse(wid.ToString()) / 2;
            int cy = int.Parse(hgt.ToString()) / 2;
            long i;
            for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                corners[i].X -= Convert.ToInt32(cx.ToString());
                corners[i].Y -= Convert.ToInt32(cy.ToString());
            }


            float theta = (float)(Angle * Math.PI / 180.0);
            float sin_theta = (float)Math.Sin(theta);
            float cos_theta = (float)Math.Cos(theta);
            float X;
            float Y;
            for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                X = corners[i].X;
                Y = corners[i].Y;
                corners[i].X = (int)(X * cos_theta + Y * sin_theta);
                corners[i].Y = (int)(-X * sin_theta + Y * cos_theta);
            }


            float xmin = corners[0].X;
            float ymin = corners[0].Y;
            for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                if (xmin > corners[i].X)
                    xmin = corners[i].X;
                if (ymin > corners[i].Y)
                    ymin = corners[i].Y;
            }
            for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                corners[i].X -= int.Parse(xmin.ToString());
                corners[i].Y -= int.Parse(ymin.ToString());
            }


            Bitmap bm_out = new Bitmap((int)(-2 * xmin), (int)(-2 * ymin));
            Graphics gr_out = Graphics.FromImage(bm_out);
            // ERROR: Not supported in C#: ReDimStatement
            Point[] temp = new Point[3];
            if (corners != null)
            {
                Array.Copy(corners, temp, Math.Min(corners.Length, temp.Length));
            }
            corners = temp;
            gr_out.DrawImage(bm_in, corners);
            return bm_out;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string s = ex.Message;
            return bm_in;
        }
    }
```

Comment: sir,I get errored if i type textbox in 4 or 180 then a eror occured:-A generic error occurred in GDI+, JPEG Image to MemoryStream.so,give suggetion..

Comment: sir,if 1 to 80 degree angle so how determine their angles,also 100 to 170,also 190 to 260 ?give response?

Comment: @user3065044: so please let me know how would you give the input is it in range like 1-80, 80-270 like that?

Comment: @user3065044 : but i don't think how to pass them as few of the types available are 90,180,270 => `RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipXY`,`RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipXY`,`RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipXY`.

Comment: no i dont want fixed angles.. i need the angles to be supplied to it and the image be rotated by it.

Comment: @user3065044: Okay, Sorry I think it should be possible. let me check once.

Comment: @user3065044: See this link -> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58815/C-Image-PictureBox-Rotations if you can not understand ,let me know.

Comment: ok,i looking it and told u if I not understand within a minute.

Comment: sir,how to set image path and textbox in this code i.e. in button click event:-

Comment: @user3065044: are you using `Winforms` or `Web`?

Comment: @user3065044: i have spent some time on the Rtating Image so i found the solution. let me post a new Answer :)

Comment: sir,i get error in this line:System.Drawing.Bitmap img = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(path)-"Parameter not valid",please reply

Comment: sir,please help me this code is not working ,u understand or not?please detect this error-System.Drawing.Bitmap img = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(path)-"Parameter not valid",and i don't understand why we use -string newpath =Server.MapPath(@"~/filename.png");,because we have already an image from Image1.ImageURL.R u here or not ,I waiting ur responce.